# Error in shinyAppDir(x) : App dir must contain either app.R or server.R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run my shiny app with the command shiny::runApp(port = 3522), but I have this error:

```
Error in shinyAppDir(x) : App dir must contain either app.R or server.R.
```

The issue is that my app.R exists, I don't know what is happening, this the structure of my directory

```
app.R
global.R
www
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is your current working directory the same as the folder where `app.R` is located? You can check with `getwd()`

Comment: No, is not the same. Is a folder inside my project.This is what I have with ```getwd()``` 
[1] "/Users/me/Documents/Tree-kg"  and my folder with all my shiny app is inside Tree-kg/myapp

Comment: You need to change your working directory to the folder with `app.R` inside. You can do so with `setwd()`.

Answer (score 1):

After publishing an app to shinyapps.io, the behavior of the Run App button of my RStudio IDE was modified to "In Background Job" instead of the usual "In R Console". I solved the issue by expanding the drop-down for Run App and selecting "In R Console". I hope this helps.